# Anylogic - Location of batching and unbatching

Tags: anylogic

I have a very simple question concerning the batching and unbatching blocks of Anylogic. I would like to batch agents at one point, move them and unbatch them at another location. However, each time it unbatches, the agents jump back to where they were batched.

Comment: Welcome to SO. That is not a question. Please actually add a question mark or rephrase the problem so it's clear what you want. Also please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve animation problem, you need to do the following:

- insert a "MoveTo" block after the "Unbatch" block
- configure the "MoveTo" block to instantly place agents to the destination point